# Customize logger for spark

Tags: spark-java

I am running *spark2.3* and want to configure the logging mechanism so that it would utilize my existing *log4j* configurations. I can't seem to find a solution to achieve this. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Maven, then just include the log4j dependency in your `pom.xml` and place the `log4j.properties` file under `src/main/resources` and Spark will handle the rest.